# What's name of UI component like this?

Tags: lists

Trying to get more examples of 3 level list component like this but don't know naming of UI component

[image]

Comment: Yes it's Miller columns, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Name of this component is Nested filter.
You can find example of this component on most of the e commerce platform.

But I think this kind of component is bed for user experience, instead we can use multi level Filter or Quick filter with limited options.